# How to prevent gorm from failing to save associations when UNIQUE constraint is violated?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following `struct`

```
type Category struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(128);not null;unique"`
}
```

which is associated to `Item` `struct`:

```
// Item is a type representing a job listing on stackoverflow jobs
type Item struct {
  GUID   string `gorm:"primary_key"`
  Link   string

  Categories []Category `gorm:"many2many:item_categories"`
}
```

I'd like to save `Item`s in db using [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) together with associations in table `item_categories`

The problem arises when I `INSERT` an `Item` which has at least on `Category` that is already in the DB (because of the `UNIQUE` constraint on `Category.Name`) then I get an error while doing:

```
var item Item
// fill item...
db.Create(&item)
```

and it propagates so that all `INSERT`s (of `Item`, `Category` and `Item_Categories`) are not performed.

I've tried using `BeforeCreate`/`AfterCreate` but the result is the same

```
func (c *Category) BeforeCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) (err error) {
  if err = scope.DB().Where(&Category{Name: c.Name}).First(c).Error; err == nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Category %s already found in DB", c.Name)
  }
  return nil
}
```

What can I do to make it insert `Item`s (and related **new** categories) with categories that are already in the DB?

Example of log I receive when adding a category (inside an `Item`) that already exists in the DB:

```
(/home/USER/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.9.4/global/src/github.com/USER/project/model.go:33)
[2018-02-19 13:42:46]  [0.17ms]  SELECT * FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (("categories"."name" = 'go')) ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
[1 rows affected or returned ]
BeforeCreate First
Category &{{4 2018-02-19 13:42:46.164188984 +0100 +0100 2018-02-19 13:42:46.164188984 +0100 +0100 <nil>} go}

(/home/USER/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.9.4/global/src/github.com/USER/project/storage.go:20)
[2018-02-19 13:42:46]  Category go already found in DB

(/home/USER/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.9.4/global/src/github.com/USER/project/storage.go:20)
[2018-02-19 13:42:46]  Category go already found in DB

(<autogenerated>:1)
[2018-02-19 13:42:46]  [0.12ms]  INSERT INTO "item_categories" ("item_guid","category_id") SELECT '157652','4'  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "item_categories" WHERE "item_guid" = '157652' AND "category_id" = '4')
[1 rows affected or returned ]

(/home/USER/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.9.4/global/src/github.com/USER/project/storage.go:20)
[2018-02-19 13:42:46]  Category go already found in DB

(/home/USER/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.9.4/global/src/github.com/USER/project/storage.go:20)
[2018-02-19 13:42:46]  Category go already found in DB
2018/02/19 13:42:46 Couldn't save job listing 157652 in db: Category go already found in DB
```